# Adobe Flash CS3: пропадают символы при анимации shape

Tags: анимация, flash, adobe

У меня пропадают заданные мной символы, когда поставил анимацию вида shape (форма).
Символы создавала типа "как фрагмент ролика". И получается, что только в ключевых кадрах остаются символы. Т.е. такакая картина примерно:

```
 1      5
 *----->*
```

И только там где звёздочки есть символы, а там где чёрточки символы пропадают.
Подскажите, пож-та, в чём ошибка?

Comment: ikot, разобрался, спасибо. Установил русский CS 5.5 - доволен) Интерфейс не особо поменялся, зато функциональность и удобность выше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Анимация SHAPE не предполагает работу с символами. Для этого больше подойдет Motion Tween. Если же Вам все таки хочется произвести анимацию формы (shape), то либо не преобразовывайте  ничего в символы, либо, если символы нужны для других целей - используйте анимацию Shape внутри символа. В последнем случае символы, с анимацией внутри, можно затем опять анимировать, создавая для них, например, анимацию Motion Tween. ;)

Comment: Спасибо. Ещё подскажи пож-та, такая проблема у меня:
Работал я сначала нормально карандашом, но в один плохой момент он стал глючить, т.е. когда ведёшь линию карандашом не видно этой линии, она становится видна только после того, как отпустил мышку( Но иногда, очень редко, всё нормально. Может я какую то настройку ничайно поставил или ещё что-то?

Comment: Вряд ли проблема в настройке - иначе оно всегда бы одинаково рисовало. Самый простой вариант - переустановите flash.
P.S. Уже кстати есть FLASH CS5

Comment: Та я знаю, что есть 5-й. А он сильно отличается cs3 по интерфейсу, т.е. я смогу по курсу по cs3 изучать cs5, конечно же без новшеств cs5?

Comment: Естественно сможете, по интерфейсу конечно есть небольшие изменения, но думаю, что Вам не будет сложно. Заодно узнаете о новых возможностях FLASH

Comment: пожалуйста, если что обращайтесь ;)

Comment: А где в cs5 изменять анимацию кадра, например на shape?

Comment: У Вас есть два ключевых кадра - начальная форма объекта и иго конечная форма. Встаньте в любой промежуточный кадр (между ключевыми кадрами), нажмите правую кнопку мыши и выберите в контекстном меню Create Shape Tween